# Introduction to Mathematical Statistics

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$ have the joint pdf $f(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4) = 24$ , $0 < X_l < X_2 <
X_3 < X_4 < 1$ , $0$ elsewhere. Find the joint pdf of $Y_1 = X_1/X_2$, $Y_2 = X_2/X_3$ , $Y_3 =
X_3/X_4$, $Y_4 = X_4$ and show that they are mutually independent.

I know they joint pdf is $24y_2(y_3^2)(y_4^2)$ but how do I show they are mutually independent?

Answer (score 1):

Their joint pdf has product form, so they are independent. Let $A, B, C \subseteq \mathbb [0,1)$ be Borel, then by Fubini
\begin{align*}
  P(Y_2 \in A, Y_3 \in B, Y_4 \in C) &= 
  \int_{A \times B \times C} 24y_2y_3^2y_4^2\, dy\\ &= \int_A 24y_2\, dy_2\int_By_3^2\,dy_3\int_C y_4^2\,dy_4\\
      &= P(Y_2 \in A)P(Y_3 \in B)P(Y_4 \in C)
\end{align*}

Comment: I know I have to find the marginal pdf first, g1(y1), g2(y2), g3(y3), g4(y4). how do I find that?

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote:

> I know the joint pdf is $24y_2(y_3^2)(y_4^2)$ but ...

Actually, this is incorrect (and has been left uncorrected for over 10 months). The joint pdf is $24y_2(y_3^2)(y_4^3)$.

To see this, let $(X_1, ..., X_4)$ have joint pdf $f(x_1, ..., x_4)$:

[image]

Then the joint pdf of random variables $(Y_1, ..., Y_4)$, say $g(y_1, ..., y_4)$, can be derived automatically with:

[image]

where I am using the `Transform` function from the `mathStatica` add-on to *Mathematica* to do the grunt work for me (I am one of the developers of the former), and with domain of support:

[image]

As to independence:  $(Y_1, ..., Y_4)$ are said to be *mutually stochastically independent* if and only if their joint pdf is equal to the product of the marginals. This is easily shown to be the case here:

[image]